# How to get the scrollPosition for nested scrolling in Compose

Tags: android, scroll, android-jetpack-compose

I have a `LazyColumn` with nested `LazyRows`:

```
    LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier
                .nestedScroll(rememberNestedScrollInteropConnection())
        ) {
            item {
                //LazyRow
            }
            item {
                //LazyRow
            }
            //More LazyRows
        }
```

I also have a `FloatingActionButton` with `AnimatedVisibility`.
Now I simply want to show the Button when the LazyColumn is ***not*** scrolled to the bottom and hide the Button if it is.

I tried using an additional `LazyListState` for the `LazyColumn` but its logic doesn't seem to work if there is an additional nestedScroll modifier.

Can somehow help?